# Automatically creating a record for the user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on status feature for my rails app. I have everything set up and it works perfectly fine. For the interface, I am using the best_in_place gem to allow users to edit in place for the status. The code is given below.

```
<% if @scoreboard.status.content.present? %>
  <div id="statuscontent">
    <%= render 'statusedit' %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'statusupdate' %>
<% end %>
```

The `statusedit` partial contains the best_in_place code and the `statusupdate`  partial contains the normal form for creating the status. Codes for both partials are given below.

statusedit

```
<%= best_in_place [@scoreboard, @status], :content, place_holder: "Enter a status", as: "textarea" %>
<%= link_to "delete", [@scoreboard, @status], method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure"} %>
```

statusupdate

```
<%= form_for [@scoreboard, @status] do |f| %>  
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, class: "form-control", id:"status"  %>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary", id: "status-button" %>  
<% end %>
```

The above code is working perfectly fine, however, I am struggling to set up the interface I want. The problem is that `best_in_place` editing only works if the status has been created before. Therefore, I have to create the status using the form and then I can use in place editing. However, I want the interface such that users can use in place editing without the need of physically creating a status first. Is there a way to create a default status for every user? Or a `before_update` function that maybe creates a status before the user tries to update.

I tried using Ajax for creating status to achieve the interface but it didn't work as intended. Also, I feel there must be a simpler solution to this problem. I tried setting `:default => "please upload status"` in the database but that doesn't actually create a default record. It acts like a placeholder but you still have to click post for the record to be created. Is there a way to somehow automatically create a default status for each user or set a value in the database. I have read a few stack-overflow posts on this but nothing really points to the right direction. There must be a simpler way of doing this in rails. Any documentation or suggestions would be a great help. As always, any help is always greatly appreciated!! Thanks
I have added the relevant migration and model files.

```
status model
    class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :scoreboard
    end

scoreboard model
    class Scoreboard < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :status
    end

Status migration file

class CreateStatuses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :statuses do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.references :scoreboard, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :statuses, :scoreboards
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies if this answer is not specific; you wrote a lot.

---

You're best setting a default value for an attribute at the **database** level.

Yes, you *can* use the [`before_create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback:

```
#app/models/scoreboard.rb
class Scoreboard < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :set_default_status

   private

   def set_default_status
      self[:status] = "default"
   end
end
```

The problem with this is that it adds application-level logic which can be handled by the db:

```
$ rails g migration CreateStatusDefault

# db/migrate/create_status_default________.rb
class CreateStatusDefault < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      change_column :scoreboards, :status, default: "Default"
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

Creating a default value in the db basically means that unless you send a value from your model at `create` / `update`, you're going to get the default.

The beauty of setting it in the DB is that your Rails app has absolutely zero work to do for it, making it much more efficient.

--

I subsequently found that your `status` "object" is actually a model in itself, which is probably where your issues are coming from.

If that is the case, you'll need to *build* the associative object before you create your main/parent one:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :statuses
   before_create -> (model) { model.statuses.build }
end
```

We use this to build a `profile` for each `User` who signs up to our applications; it creates a "blank" associative record for your parent model.

This is something which would give you a "blank" status object, but as you've not posted your code, I really don't know.

---

A good tip with SO is `code` > `text`.

If in doubt, post code.

Answer (score 2):

Answer for your questions.

> Is there a way to create a default status for every user ?

Yes

You could create a default record in database after [change_column](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column).

```
def up
  change_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false   # I'm assuming you are saving default as false in users table but you could change accordingly all thing. 
end
```

> `before_update` function that maybe creates a status before the user tries to update.

instead of `before_update` one could use `after_save` callback.

[As mentioned in official Document](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#updating-an-object)

> after_save runs both on create and update, but always after the more
>   specific callbacks after_create and after_update, no matter the order
>   in which the macro calls were executed.

And lastly

> There must be a simpler way of doing this in rails

Use ActiveRecord Migrations.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create a default status for every user?

**Yep** you can write it yourself. Something like this ...

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statuses
  after_create :create_first_status

  def create_first_status
    self.statuses.create some_status_attribute: "some value"
  end
end
```